# Impala query: Exception: Syntax error caused by cast function

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have the following Impala query

```
select session_id, max(cast(milli_ts) as integer), min(cast(milli_ts) as integer)from my_table group by session_id
```

But got the following errors:

```
HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 10:
...sion_id, max(cast(milli_ts) as integer), min(cast(mill...
                             ^
Encountered: )
Expected: AND, AS, BETWEEN, DIV, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, NOT, OR, REGEXP, RLIKE

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

Any idea what I missed? Thanks!

Comment: use `cast(max(milli_ts) as integer),cast(min(milli_ts) as integer)` or `max(cast(milli_ts as integer)),min(cast(milli_ts as integer))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for CAST is as following:

```
cast(milli_ts as integer)
```